# Mac won't boot up using Bootcamp after trying to resize partitions

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

my son is working on a 2012 Macbook Pro - 2.5Ghz Intwl Core i5 and running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6. The machine was split into two partitions and windows bootcamp was loaded. My son told me that every time he tried to save a document on the windows side he got error message about no available disk space. I tried to resize the windows disk partition and when we tried to start-up again, bootcamp would not load (error saying no bootable device).

I have read through as many similar questions and answers as I can but am not able to solve the problem. REALLY want to avoid paying to have the windows reloaded. Any way someone in the know could help me?

Thanks KD

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you ededit t this to clarify why payment is involved - also linking to the questions you read pr ents someone from rehashing the answers there. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like @KDempers thinks they will have to pay for a new license key.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows installation is probably permanently ruined.

Disk Utility can't resize NTFS partitions correctly. When it tries to, it corrupts some of the data inside. Unfortunately, Windows may not be able to boot anymore.

What you *can* do, however, is try to mount the partition (usually labeled BOOTCAMP) in macOS and copy whatever important files you have there onto a backup drive or other external/internal storage.

Sorry to say, but Windows may not boot ever again.

I once made this exact mistake and had to reinstall Windows completely.

Comment: Ugh! I thought that might be the case. I am busy copying the important files. Will take the machine in to have the Windows reinstalled tomorrow. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem :)